# Check isogram c++ using unordered set

Tags: c++, c++11

Iam using `unordered_set` in C++ to check isogram words.

```
struct CustomHasher {
    size_t operator()(const char& c) const;
};

// This hashing function should take the given character c and return an integer
// representing the hash value. This will be computed by the position of a-z,
// where a=>0, b=>1, and so on.
size_t CustomHasher::operator()(const char& c) const {

size_t i = tolower(c) - 'a';
return i;

}

void add_multiset(const string& s,
unordered_multiset<char, CustomHasher>* ms) {

for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    ms->insert(tolower(s[i]));
}

// inside main function

unordered_multiset<char, CustomHasher> ms;
add_multiset("hello", &ms);
```

What is wrong with my code? when I check the output of: `ms.bucket('l')` I should get 11, but instead I get 7

Also `ms.bucket('o')` I get 6, but instead I should get 14
What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

The bucket number is not necessarily equal to the hash. For a nearly empty `unordered_multiset` you would expect many hashes to share the same bucket.

Since `unordered_multiset` is a template class, you can easily trace into the code to find out exactly how it's calculating the bucket number based on the hash.

Comment: I know there are many ways to do it, but I want to know using my own method what is the problem ?

Comment: Your problem is that you assume the hash code and the bucket number should be the same. They aren't.

Comment: can you explain how ill fix my operator() code please?
I put comments, but for my code and for bucjet it should return alphabet is position using my function thanks

Comment: @salim.p that's what I'm trying to tell you, your code is working exactly as it should. It is your expectation that is wrong.